# Цикл for и его перезапуск в python

Tags: python, циклы

Запускаю цикл и в нем если не устраивает значение в `arr` удаляю ту часть которая не устраивает

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if i == some:
        arr.pop(i)
```

И тогда получается что `len(arr)` станет на `1` меньше и при следующем разе `i` получит значение из старого `len(arr)`, а он уже изменился и получится что можно получить ошибку

> list index out of range

А надо бы цикл перезапустить с той же `i` на которой остановились, или как-то по другому сделать цикл?

Comment: Та же задача очистки списка сокетов от закрывшихся нештатно?

Comment: Ты тут) Да, очистка сокетов))

Comment: В цикл редактировать объект, по по которому проходится цикл, в питоне нельзя. Можно например `arr = [x for x in arr if нужное-условие-по-x]`

Comment: Что-то не понял как это использовать, но придумал вот что, после выполнения for записывать в переменную индексы которые нужно удалить, и после цикла удалять

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas простая запись индексов как есть приведёт к той же самой проблеме, нужно сортировать их по убыванию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, не надо обходить список, создавая диапазон по длине списка. Можно просто:

```
for s in socket_list:
    ...
```

Во-вторых, как я уже писал в прошлом вопросе, нельзя изменять список, по которому идёт итерация. Можно вести отдельный список сбойных сокетов и удалить их после цикла. Наконец, в вашем случае лучше использовать множества, а не списки. Подытоживая всё написанное:

```
closed_sockets = set()
for s in sockets:
    try:
        # Операции с сокетом
    except socket.error as e:
        # Какие-либо дополнительные проверки типа ошибки
        closed_sockets.add(s)
sockets -= closed_sockets # При условии, что sockets - множество
```

**UPDATE:** Судя по ошибке `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration`, когда изменений множества в самом цикле не происходит, его изменяет другой поток. Поэтому для итерации стоит создать копию, а изменение глобальной переменной блокировать:

```
closed_sockets = set()
for s in set(sockets):
    try:
        # Операции с сокетом
    except socket.error as e:
        # Какие-либо дополнительные проверки типа ошибки
        closed_sockets.add(s)
with threading.Lock():
    sockets -= closed_sockets
```

Не забудьте добавить такую же блокировку в том месте, где в множество добавляются элементы.

Comment: Сейчас попробую переделать sockets в множества, просто никогда с ними не работал, и посмотрю как будет работать.

Comment: Что означает RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration? У меня появились проблемы с получением сообщений на сервер, 1 сообщение доходит, а 2 нет

Comment: Ошибка в этой части кода:
 'for i in conn:
            try:
                data = i.recv(1024)
                if data:
                    print(data.decode())
            except:
                pass'

Comment: Какая ошибка? Текст ошибки?

Comment: RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration

Comment: Заблокировал я при подключении, при удалении, но прием сообщения так и остался с ошибкой, что не так?

Comment: Весь код [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/XBnx4aHL), можешь глянуть еще как принимать сервером сообщения без цикла, чтобы сразу всех принимать?

Comment: `for i in set(conn):`

Comment: Хорошо, эту проблему решили, как теперь решить с приемом сообщений? Подключений я наверное ограничу в 1024, т.к. выйдет в 1 мб соединение, уже не малая нагрузка, а может и вовсе в 512, не буду же я делать 512 проверок? Это самое сложное, даже идей нет

Comment: Не понял. Проверок на что?

Comment: Циклов* data = i.recv(1024) он ждет пока придет сообщение, и дальше не пойдет ведь.

Comment: Либо на каждый сокет создавать отдельный поток, либо использовать поллинг неблокирующихся сокетов. Но это уже повод для нового вопроса, если сами не разберётесь ;)

Comment: Сам точно не разберусь, я даже идей не имел, сейчас новый вопрос задам)

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо изолировать Ваш цикл, например заключив его в функцию:

```
def del_item(some_list):
    my_len = len(some_list)
    for i in sorted(range(my_len), reverse=True):  # реверсный список индексов
        if i == some_condition:
            some_list.pop(i)
```

Но стоит обратить внимание на то, что такая функция изменит переданный ей список, что может привести к потере данных. Дабы этого избежать, можно воспользоваться генераторным выражением, которое значительно економит память при работе с большими списками и создает новый список по условию:

```
>>> s = [1, 3, 5, 2, 2]
>>> [i for i in s if i != 2]
[1, 3, 5]
```